# Quanteda group documents by multiple variables

Tags: r, nlp, quanteda

I would like to be able to group documents in my dfm by two variables - speaker and week_start. I was previously able to do this using
`dfm(corpus, groups=c("speaker","week_start")`. This worked fine and grouped documents by speaker-week.

However, with the recent updates to the quanteda package I seem to be running into a few problems. So I now create the dfm first then I try to group. Below is the code

```
dfm <- dfm(corpus)
dfm <- dfm_group(dfm, groups = c(speaker, week_start))
```

However, when I do this I get the error:

> Error: groups must have length ndoc(x)

I have also tried to put the docvars in quotations but this generates the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We changed the usage of the `groups` argument in v3 to make it more standard.

From `news(Version >= "3.0", package = "quanteda")`:

> We have added non-standard evaluation for `by` and `groups` arguments
> to access object docvars:
>
> - The `*_sample()` functions' argument `by`, and `groups` in the `*_group()` functions, now take unquoted document variable (docvar)
>   names directly, similar to the way the `subset` argument works in the
>   `*_subset()` functions.
> - Quoted docvar names no longer work, as these will be evaluated literally.
> - The `by = "document"` formerly sampled from `docid(x)`, but this functionality is now removed.  Instead, use `by = docid(x)` to
>   replicate this functionality.
> - For `groups`, the default is now `docid(x)`, which is now documented more completely.  See `?groups` and `?docid`.

So, to get the previous behaviour, you would want to use:

```r
groups = interaction(speaker, week_start)
```

Here's an example:

```r
library("quanteda")
## Package version: 3.0
## Unicode version: 13.0
## ICU version: 69.1
## Parallel computing: 12 of 12 threads used.
## See https://quanteda.io for tutorials and examples.

corp <- corpus(c(
  "a b c",
  "a c d",
  "c d d",
  "d d e"
),
docvars = data.frame(
  var1 = c("a", "a", "b", "b"),
  var2 = c(1, 2, 1, 1)
)
)
corp %>%
  tokens() %>%
  dfm() %>%
  dfm_group(groups = interaction(var1, var2))
## Document-feature matrix of: 3 documents, 5 features (40.00% sparse) and 2 docvars.
##      features
## docs  a b c d e
##   a.1 1 1 1 0 0
##   b.1 0 0 1 4 1
##   a.2 1 0 1 1 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, that makes sense. However, when I run that code on my corpus I get the error - `Error in qatd_cpp_is_grouped_character(x, group) : Invalid groups`. 

If I go step by step - tokenise my corpus, and then create the dfm, then my two docvars are there so I'm not sure how to interpret that error...

Comment: You'd need to supply a reproducible example for that, or file an issue if you think it's a bug (with enough data to reproduce it).

Comment: Managed to resolve it, thanks for the both responses.